# Symbolic expression for recursion

Tags: recursion

Is it possible to get symbolic expression for recursive function? In particular I am checking if a symbolic expression is possible (i.e. f[n]) for the following code:

```
f[x_] := If[x > 1, 2*f[x - 1] + 1, 1]
f[#] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

> f[#] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

I tried using `Nest[]`, but I suppose it is not applicable in this case, as it works for numeric depth.

Comment: Check documentation for `RSolve`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Could you post an answer so that I can accept? I used `RSolve[f[n] - 2 f[n - 1] - 1 == 0, f[n], n][[1, 1]] /. C[1] -> 0` and got the expression.

Comment: no replacement rule is needed if you supply a boundary condition `RSolveValue[{f[n] == 2 f[n - 1] + 1, f[1] == 1}, f[n], n]`

Comment: I put it in a community wiki response, but I'd not be surprised if the question gets closed anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sort of thing is handled by `RSolve`.

```
RSolve[{f[n] - 2 f[n - 1] - 1 == 0, f[1] == 1}, f[n], n]

(* Out[115]= {{f[n] -> -1 + 2^n}} *)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
f[x_] := If[x > 1, 2*f[x - 1] + 1, 1];
f[#] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

(*

{1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255, 511}

*)

```
FindSequenceFunction[{1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255, 511}]
```

(*

-1 + 2^#1 &

*)

The above is the inferred expression uses all the information of the recursive definition and can be written $f(j) = -1 + 2^j$.

Check:

```
-1 + 2^#1 & /@ Range[9]
```

(*

{1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255, 511}

*)

Comment: How can I get the expression? If not, this procedure shall restrict me to Mathematica itself.

Comment: The expression is given as the result:  $f(j) = -1 + 2^j$ (where $j$ is the iteration number).  What more could you ask for?!

Comment: I didn't get the significance of `#1` in the beginning. Thanks for explaining. Although your answer is correct, I found using `RSolve` more elegant in mathematical sense as it uses information of the recursive function.

Comment: Gosh... so note even a simple upvote!